# Div element for new section hidden behind container

Tags: javascript, html, css, containers

I'm fairly new to HTML and still learning and now I'm stuck with something:

I finished making an image carousel and I cannot add a second container under the carousel (its own section). The second container is hiding behind the first one.

```
html, body {
  background-color: rgba(206, 199, 199, 0.458);
  height: 200%;
  position:static;
  font-family: sans-serif; 
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  border: rgb(22, 19, 19) dotted 2px;
  
}

.logo {
  position:absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 1%;
}

.logo2 {
  position:absolute;
  width: 550px;
  height: 120px;
  outline-style:groove;
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-offset: -20px;
  top: 10%;

  left:9%;   
}

h1 {
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-shadow: red 400%;
  left: 450px;
  top: 240px;
  border: rgb(37, 56, 184) dotted 3px;
}
 
#container{
  background-color: rgb(253, 250, 250);
  height: 20%;
  width:  100%;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0%;
  
}
   
#main-menu .nav-bar { 
  position:absolute;
  list-style:none; 
  top: 50px;
  left: 95vh;
}

#main-menu .nav-bar li { 
  display:inline-block; 
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#main-menu .nav-bar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.2s 0s;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main-menu .nav-bar li a:hover{ 
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

Main#carousel {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
  --items: 5;
  --middle: 3;
  --position: 1;
  pointer-events:none;
  top: 800px;
  border: red dotted 5px;
}


body {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 940px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  border: rgb(56, 169, 44) dotted 5px;
}
  
div.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: coral;
  --r: calc(var(--position) - var(--offset));
  --abs: max(calc(var(--r) * -1), var(--r));
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transform: rotateY(calc(-10deg * var(--r)))
  translateX(calc(-250px * var(--r)));
  z-index: calc((var(--position) - var(--abs)));
}
  
div.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  --offset: 1;
  background-image: url(photos/Alluredbyyou.jpg);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center; 
}

div.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  --offset: 2;
  background-image: url(photos/Notyourmarrysue.jpg);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  --offset: 3;
  background-image: url(photos/thewolf.png);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  --offset: 4;
  background-image: url(photos/adreamof.jpg);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(5) {
  --offset: 5;
  background-image: url(photos/EJ.png);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

input:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ main#carousel{
  --position: 1;
}
  
input:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ main#carousel {
  --position: 2;
}

input:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 4 /5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ main#carousel {
  --position: 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ main#carousel {
  --position: 4;
}

input:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-column: 6 / 7;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ main#carousel {
  --position: 5;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="photos/ae_logo.png">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
<img class="logo2"  src="photos/title.png" alt="" srcset="">
<img class="logo"  src="photos/ae_logo.png" alt="" srcset="">

<h1>NEW RELEASES</h1>

<nav id="main-menu">
  <ul class="nav-bar">
    <li class="nav-button-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button-books"><a href="#">Books</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button-authors"><a href="#">Authors</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button-submissions"><a href="#">Submissions</a></li>
    <li class="nav-button-contact"><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
         

  </div> 
  
  
  
  <main id="carousel">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
  </main>
  </body>

  <main>
  
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </main>
 </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have not closed the `<main>` tag, so the new section got included into it.

Comment: Which main tag? I can't see it.

Comment: `<main id="carousel">`

Comment: Oh, now I see it. I closed it now but still get the issue. I'm not so good at adding positions.

could you take a look at my updated version?

Comment: There are more wrong tags, e.g. some extra closing `</div>` tags. In my opinion, you're trying to do too much at the same time. I'd try to fix your HTML first, and start with very basic CSS, no colors, no formatting, just the layout stuff. Once this is done and everything is in the right position, add the details. And, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try to add as little code as possible and describe your problem well.

Comment: @Christian Hi. I managed to figure it out. You were right about the divs and all those things. I sorted everything out by starting over. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could fix your code and achieve what you are looking for, after I have fixed the indentation in your example.

[image]

#### Indenting your code is important

Indentation of elements is needed to understand what's going on. Maybe the site screwed up your indentation. If not, try to indent any nested elements properly in the future. Learn more on [why indentation is important](https://dev.to/sanjaysinghrajpoot/why-indentation-is-more-important-than-coding-4fn1).

#### What I have done

- I have removed some extra closing tags, for example `</body>` tag and some `</div>` tags.
- I have changed the absolute positioned elements h1 and carousel to relatively positioned elements to let your layout "flow".

Learn more on [when absolute positioned elements are useful](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/#aa-absolute). I have exchanged their fixed positioning with `margin` (**t**op/**r**ight**b**ottom/**l**eft/) - I love this "trouble" mnemonic :)

#### Code to get the result above

```css
html, body {
  background-color: rgba(206, 199, 199, 0.458);
  height: 200%;
  position:static;
  font-family: sans-serif; 
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  border: rgb(22, 19, 19) dotted 2px;
  
}

.logo {
  position:absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 1%;
}

.logo2 {
  position:absolute;
  width: 550px;
  height: 120px;
  outline-style:groove;
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-offset: -20px;
  top: 10%;

  left:9%;   
}

h1 {
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-shadow: red 400%;
  margin: 200px 0 200px 0;
  border: rgb(37, 56, 184) dotted 3px;
}
 
#container{
  background-color: rgb(253, 250, 250);
  height: 20%;
  width:  100%;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0%;
}
   
#main-menu .nav-bar { 
  position:absolute;
  list-style:none; 
  top: 50px;
  left: 95vh;
}

#main-menu .nav-bar li { 
  display:inline-block; 
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#main-menu .nav-bar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.2s 0s;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main-menu .nav-bar li a:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

Main#carousel {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
  --items: 5;
  --middle: 3;
  --position: 1;
  pointer-events:none;
  margin-top: 300px;
  border: red dotted 5px;
}

body {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 940px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  border: rgb(56, 169, 44) dotted 5px;
}
  
div.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: coral;
  --r: calc(var(--position) - var(--offset));
  --abs: max(calc(var(--r) * -1), var(--r));
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transform: rotateY(calc(-10deg * var(--r)))
  translateX(calc(-250px * var(--r)));
  z-index: calc((var(--position) - var(--abs)));
}
  
div.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  --offset: 1;
  background-image: url(photos/Alluredbyyou.jpg);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center; 
}

div.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  --offset: 2;
  background-image: url(photos/Notyourmarrysue.jpg);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  --offset: 3;
  background-image: url(photos/thewolf.png);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  --offset: 4;
  background-image: url(photos/adreamof.jpg);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(5) {
  --offset: 5;
  background-image: url(photos/EJ.png);
  height:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

input:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ main#carousel{
  --position: 1;
}
  
input:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ main#carousel {
  --position: 2;
}

input:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 4 /5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ main#carousel {
  --position: 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
input:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ main#carousel {
  --position: 4;
}

input:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-column: 6 / 7;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
input:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ main#carousel {
  --position: 5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="photos/ae_logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <img class="logo2"  src="photos/title.png" alt="" srcset="">
      <img class="logo"  src="photos/ae_logo.png" alt="" srcset="">

      <h1>NEW RELEASES</h1>

      <nav id="main-menu">
        <ul class="nav-bar">
          <li class="nav-button-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-button-books"><a href="#">Books</a></li>
          <li class="nav-button-authors"><a href="#">Authors</a></li>
          <li class="nav-button-submissions"><a href="#">Submissions</a></li>
          <li class="nav-button-contact"><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div> 
  
    <main id="carousel">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </main>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="photo">div for photo</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```